# UItableView custom cell with a plus button on the left side (outside table view)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add a plus button outside my table view cell (on the left side), but the button should get scrolled if I am scrolling the table. Does anyone has a solution for this??? Also, there are 8 different sections in my table. There is no need to show that plus button for the first 7 sections, but there is a plus button in the 8th section clicking on which will increase the number of sections by 1. (the catch here is that the plus button is NOT INSIDE THE CELL and there are different sections where we will not show the plus button, so no UNIFORMITY).

Answer (score 0):

I belive that the best solution to this is to create a custom section header (or footer) view and put the button there. It will "look" like it's outside the table, but it will be inside the given view.

In your case, only inside the section header/footer of section 7.

That button will scrool along with the table, as the section header/footer will.

Or, alternatively, you could have an "empty" section 8 (with no rows, but with a header) and display the button there. If you want the button displayed, you should return the number of section as "8", if you want the button hidden, return section count as "7".

Comment: Thanks Sergio, but I want to add that button sideways of the row 1 of section 8. What you are suggesting is to add that button in header or footer which I dont require.

Comment: @anshul so, I assume your tableView has a smaller width than usual? Do you have a mockup of what you want? If the button is sideways of the cell with the "normal" width, it would end up outside of the screen (mostly at least).

Comment: Hey Sergio, I got the answer. Since table view is a sub class of UIScrollView, so I have implemented the method:  - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView of UIScrollViewDelegate and within this method I have code for scrolling the UIButton (which would get scrolled with table view) which I have placed sideways. So, ultimately the button is outside the table view and secondly, It will get scrolled with the table. ;) :) :D

Comment: @anshul, you could post your own answer and mark it as accepted for future readers and to close the question!